# Override CSS for Rich Text Editor Salesforce

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm developing a Salesforce Lightning Web Component (LWC) that includes a Rich Text Editor (RTE) feature. When users click on the "Link" button icon within the RTE, a popup appears to allow them to enter text and a URL to create a link. However, the labels for both fields and the entered text are not visible within the popup.

I've inspected the HTML elements of the RTE and the popup, but I'm having difficulty identifying the specific CSS classes or IDs to target for customization. I would like to modify the appearance of this popup to ensure that the labels and entered text are visible to users.

[image]

What are the recommended approaches for customizing the CSS of the Link URL input popup within a Salesforce Lightning Web Component Rich Text Editor? Are there specific CSS classes or IDs that I should be targeting for customization? Alternatively, are there any alternative methods or attributes that can be used to achieve this customization?

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to address this issue effectively. Thank you!